# Constructing invariant subspaces from scratch. An algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So, basically i am trying to prove that there exist a basis w.r.t which there exists an upper triangular matrix in a complex field.
Most of the books which i read incorporate induction as a method which i find sadly non intuitive. Please have a look at the following :

Suppose in the complex field, I select an eigen vector $v_1$ such that $Tv_1 = kv_1$.

Now, i must select a vector $v_2$ such that:

(a) $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.
(b) $Tv_2$ lies in span$(v_1,v_2)$.

Writing mathematically, $v_2$ should be such that

(i) $rv_1 + sv_2 = 0 \implies r = s = 0$.

(ii) $Tv_2 = a v_1 + b v_2 \implies (T - b I )v_2 = av_1$

What can I infer for $v_2$ from here?

Some points which may be helpful like:

$av_1$ lies in range $(T - b I)$

Now since the range of any linear mapping is a subspace,
$v_1$ also lies in the range $(T - b I)$.

Help will be really appreciated as I have spent a long time analyzing this. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear... I assume you have a complex vector space $V$ and an endomorphism $T: V \rightarrow V$. You want to find a basis $B$ such that the representation ${}^BT^B$ of $T$ with regard to this basis is (upper) triangular. Correct?

Comment: @m_l Yes. That's correct. So, i tried moving in steps, first trying to find a linearly independent vector v2 (w.r.t v1) such that T v2 = span(v1,v2)

Comment: Any directions/suggestions in this path. I tried thinking on the above path taken, i wouldn't want to abandon it though it doesn't show much promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, think about the linear transformation an upper triangular matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \ast & \ast \\
0 & \lambda_2 & \ast \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \end{pmatrix}$$
represents.

It takes $e_3$ to $\lambda_3 e_3$ -- that is, it fixes $\operatorname{span} \{e_3\}$.  It takes $e_2$ to a linear combination of $e_2$ and $e_3$; since it also takes $e_3$ to a linear combination of $e_2$ and $e_3$ (specifically, a linear combination where the coefficient of $e_2$ is zero!), this means it also fixes $\operatorname{span} \{e_2, e_3\}$.  And of course it fixes $\operatorname{span} \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$, which in this case is not saying anything because that's the entire space.

So, a matrix in upper triangular form gives us

1. a line fixed by the transformation;
2. a plane fixed by the transformation and containing that line;
3. a three-space fixed by the transformation and containing that plane;
4. and so forth up to the dimension of $n$.

Consequently, to put a matrix in upper triangular form, we should reverse this process by finding such a line, then such a plane, etc.

Comment: Yep, true that. But, will the reverse process be always valid in a complex vector space?

Comment: Well, you have to prove that it can be done, but, yes, it can.  If you know (1) that every complex linear operator has an eigenvector and (2) what a quotient vector space is, then this is obvious.

Comment: If you don't know what a quotient space is then you can still prove it (essentially by just converting the notion of a quotient space to more elementary language), but the proof isn't particularly enlightening IMHO.

Comment: @Vish Yes, the reverse process will always work. You are looking for the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). There are standard algorithms to compute it.

Comment: Jordan normal form is WAY more than he's looking for...

Comment: How so? An algorithm to find invariant spaces is (almost) an algorithm to find the basis for a Jordan normal form. I agree that it is more, but I don't see the *WAY*.

Comment: He's having trouble understanding a simple algorithm to put a matrix into upper triangular form.  I don't think that moving to a substantially more complicated version of the same algorithm is quite what's called for pedagogically...

Comment: @m_l and Daniel The book which i am reading ( linear algebra done right by sheldon axler ) mentions the jordan form much later. So, I haven't gone that far but i will try reading on it and quotient space.
But, any Thoughts/inferences on the way i moved in the proof?

Comment: I concede that the Jordan form has technical difficulties (and thus is not called for here). Don't read it yet.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I finally found a proof using quotient spaces. Thank you.